# HIghCharts PHP MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I am a newcomer to Highcharts and trying to learn how to use it with PHP and MySQL. I would like to display a simple column chart from some sample data in an array. However, I having some problems implementing this. The columns are not showing up in the chart and I am getting an extra label that is blank in the legend.  If someone could help me to clean up this code, make it work and provide sample code with commenting to help better understand it, that would a big help.  I'm sure several other people are also looking for a similar example.  I have looked through this site and through the HighCharts forum and examples and could not find exactly what I was looking for that could better help me to learn how to create dynamic column type charts using PHP and MySQL. If you can help many Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I have, I know it has several problems and I tried to keep this as a short example that is easy enough for newbies and students to understand. Your help is greatly appreciated:

My sample data contains the lastname and sales amount for that person. It is in a TSV format and the array looks like this:  Doe 3567 Right 5476 Johnson 4351 Brown 2945

data.php

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("test", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo $row['lastname'] . "\t" . $row['sales']. "\n";
    }
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
</head><body>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; width: 900px"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    var options = {
        chart: {renderTo: 'container', defaultSeriesType:'column', height: 400},
        title: {text: 'Sales Performance'},
        xAxis: {title: {text: 'Sales Peoples'}, type: 'linear'},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Dollars'}, plotLines: [{ value: 0, width: 1, color: '#808080'}]},
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+'('+this.x +' : '+ this.y +')';
            }
        },
        legend: {layout: 'vertical', align: 'left', verticalAlign: 'top', x: 40, y: 100,   borderWidth: 0, width: 300 },
        series: []
    };

    jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(tsv) {
        var data = {};
        tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g); // split into rows
        for (var row=0, rows=tsv.length; row<rows; row++) {
            var line = tsv[row].split(/\t/g), // split into columns
                series_name = line[0],
                x = Number(line[1]),
                y = Number(line[2]);
            if (!data[series_name]) data[series_name] = [];
            data[series_name].push([x,y]);
            //alert("The data is: "+series_name)
        }
        for (var series_name in data) {
            options.series.push({
                name: series_name,
                data: data[series_name]
            });
        }
        new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });

});
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Tutorial can help you out http://sgeek.org/create-chart-using-mysql-highcharts/

Answer (score 1):

> data[series_name].push([x,y]);

```
data[series_name].push(x);
```

You  haven't `y` and `line[2]`

Comment: Hi Kazatca, thanks for your reply.  That helped clean it up some but its still not working.  I tried your suggestions and I also modified this line for the formater. `return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+'('+this.x +')';`

Comment: After implementing the suggestion from Kazatca,  I put an alert on series_name and x.  From that I can see after  `tsv = tsv.split`  I have a blank value in the name and that triggers a NaN for the last value of x.  From what I have read that will cause the Chart not to display in HighCharts which is the problem now.  If someone could help me with some code to check for blank values and remove them if they or NaN exist that would probably clean this up and make it display the chart.  I’m still a learning newbie and I’m not sure how to do that programmatically.  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: tsv.split(/\n/) returns ["some data","some data",""] always because tsv  ends in "\n". try implode("\n",$collected) on the server side.